# Multi statement-conditional MySQL transaction in Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js

The case is to:

Check if record in database exists:
if yes, return record
if no, add to table 1, update table 2 and return record (everything in transaction)
process record

How to do it elegantly? Could you provide some example?

Comment: You can solve this using knex.js (http://knexjs.org/) If you have any problems using knex you can update your question

Comment: Have you tried anything, please post code if you did.